# Inline code editor is not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am uploading the zip file which contains all the python files and dependencies to the AWS Lambda, and it's working perfectly without any error.

However the `Edit code inline` function is not working. I have to upload the whole zip file again and again whenever I am making any changes. And it is happening just for this Lambda function. Inline editor in other functions are working file.

[image]

[image]

Am I missing something?

Comment: This generally happens when there is a mismatch in your Lambda function configuration. Can you check if you have `lambda_handler` function defined in your `test.py`?

Comment: @KrishnaKumarR yes its there, and code is not throwing any error.

Comment: How big is your deployment package?

Comment: @KrishnaKumarR it was around 3.2 mb

Answer (score 3):

It is due to the size of your function.
If you try to reduce the size of the function then it will show up in online code editor.

It is good practice to use base packages instead of custom libraries in aws-lambda.

Comment: Upto what zip size it will show inline edit ... any idea

Comment: yes you are right, now there is a message displayed by AWS `The deployment package of your Lambda function is too large to enable inline code editing. However, you can still invoke your function right now.`

Comment: @ifti If you want inline code editing, the zipped deployment package should not exceed 3 MB. Also check out the other limits [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html#limits-list)

Answer (score 1):

This typically indicates the uploaded Lambda (zip file) exceeds the max allowable size for AWS to display the inline code editor. The limit currently is **3 MB** as far as zipped lambda import.

[image]

It will still work, but you cannot use/view the inline code editor.

If you are using aws-sdk you can omit this from included libs as it is made available by default and does take up a lot of space.

You might want to consider changing your lambda dev workflow, utilizing something like [lambda-toolkit](https://github.com/lucioveloso/lambda-toolkit) (or just AWS CLI) to create/edit/test locally and then push to AWS for deployment only.

Answer (score 0):

Few things to make the size of package small and being able to view the code online:

- Boto3 is already part of the lambda run time so not needed to add in requirements.txt
- Instead of adding requests module in requirements.txt we can use urllib3 that is already part of the lambda run time

So following these 2 steps I am able to view the code in the code tab. Also this makes the lambda light weight and package size small.

Example:

```
    def send_request(method, url, payload = {}):
        import urllib3
        http = urllib3.PoolManager()
        response = http.request(method, url, fields=payload)
        status_code = response.status
        content = response.data.decode('utf-8')
        data = json.loads(content)
        return data, status_code
```

Use:

```
data, status_code = send_request("GET", "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1")
print(data, status_code)
```